# database table design foreign key to multiple table

Tags: php, postgresql, foreign-keys

In my PHP and psql application, I have large number of customers and service providers, both can login to the system, for login details we created a table USER but how can we map both CUSTOMER table and SERVICE_PROVIDER table in the USER table as foreign key. The structure Skeleton is

```
**CUSTOMER:** 
id    bigserial, 
name  character varying(100),
address character varying(350),
phone character varying(50),
etc....

**SERVICE_PROVIDER:**
id bigserial, 
name  character varying(100),
email  character varying(100),
phno  character varying(50),
first_esc  character varying(100),
sec  character varying(100),
etc


**USER**
id bigserial, 
username  character varying(100),
password  character varying(100),
customer_type  bigint
```

In USER Table column customer_type may either Customer or Service Provider

How to design the table structure....

Please help me

Thanking You
Anju

Comment: In User table set column `user_type` and `user_id`. `user_type` it may enum type value of `CUSTOMER` or `SERVICE_PROVIDER`

Comment: You can't create a foreign key to two different tables easily. You'd need two columns in `user` - `customer_id` and `service_provider_id`, and you'd need to add a `CHECK (customer_id IS NULL != service_provider_id IS NULL)` constraint that forced exactly one of them to be non-null. Consider table inheritance as an alternative model to foreign keys for this use.

Comment: thak yo for your suggestion,  I just mentioned only two tables... district level users can also login to this system....I need a correct way of design..

Answer (score 0):

What is needed is FKs from multiple other groups (subtypes) to (supertype) user.

Every table has a statement. The rows that make the statement true go in the table. Customers are users and service providers are users. So when CUSTOMER & SERVICE_PROVIDER (etc) say something is true about a person, USER says something about them.

```
// "customer [id] has ..."
CUSTOMER(id,...)
    fk id references USER -- a customer is a user

// "service provider [id] has ..."
SERVICE_PROVIDER(id,....)
    fk id references USER -- a service provider is a user

// "user [id] has ..."
USER(id,...)
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24421797/3404097).